# How to access a dictionary object inside a dictionary(with for loop)? Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I'd like to figure out the percentage of the number of first orders and the request count, or how many times the customers requested this product.

the metrics for this is a dict inside of a dict

like so:

`{'product_name': 'Passion Fruit Flavored Fruit Juice Cocktail Blend', 'department_id': '7', 'metrics': {'request_count': 289, 'number_of_first_orders': 82}}`

My code to do this right now is:

```
for entry in products:

   percentage = round(float(products[entry]["metrics"]["number_of_first_orders"]) / total_for_department[products[entry]["department_id"]] , 2)

   #print products[entry]["metrics"]["number_of_first_orders"] ,  total_for_department[products[entry]["department_id"]]
   #print percentage

   # go through all the products and output the metrics   
   print(products[entry]["department_id"], ",",products[entry]["metrics"]["request_count"], ",",products[entry]["metrics"]["number_of_first_orders"], ",", percentage)
```

After running this however, I get a traceback that I understand, but I'm unsure how to acess a dict inside of a dict and the syntax.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-2972dc07d77f>", line 3, in <module>
    percentage = round(float(products[entry]["metrics"]["number_of_first_orders"]) / total_for_department[products[entry]["department_id"]] , 2)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look into the `values` method on `dicts`. It would help clean up your code.

Comment: Shoud you use `total_for_department[int(products[entry]["department_id"])]` to cast a `str` to `int`?

Comment: @Doba and how do you get `(.5)`, logically?

Comment: Are you trying to divide `number_of_first_orders / department_id`? even then it would be `82/7` = `11.71`?

Comment: @Dirtybit I apologize, but yeah haha not very intuitive. PEBCAK Error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
products = [
{'product_name': 'Passion Fruit Flavored Fruit Juice Cocktail Blend',
'department_id': '7',
'metrics': {'request_count': 289, 'number_of_first_orders': 82}},

{'product_name': 'Passion Fruit Flavored Fruit Juice Cocktail Blend',
'department_id': '7',
'metrics': {'request_count': 289, 'number_of_first_orders': 90}}
]
```

When you're iterating over `products` with `for entry in products`, `entry` is a dictionary in the `products` list. So you can simply access the value of `number_of_first_orders` like this:

```
number_of_first_orders = entry["metrics"]["number_of_first_orders"]
```

Using the list above, the following code:

```
for entry in products:
    number_of_first_orders = entry["metrics"]["number_of_first_orders"]
    print(number_of_first_orders)
```

outputs:

```
82
90
```

Then, you're trying to access an element of the `total_for_department` list using the value of `"department_id"` but that value is a string not an integer. Cast it to an `int` first to get a valid index:

```
total_for_department[int(entry["department_id"])]
```

So the full line should look like:

```
percentage = round(float(entry["metrics"]["number_of_first_orders"]) / total_for_department[int(entry["department_id"])] , 2)
```

Comment: You didn't catch the problem .... he was accessing a list which he already understood . let's guess ... where is the list?  LOL.

Comment: Also, the goal is to get the percentage of something that is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a late night and easy fix, but thanks to @shawn and his smart comments + the people who tried, the answer hit me.

```
   for entry in products:

   percentage = (float(products[entry]["metrics"]["number_of_first_orders"]) / products[entry]["metrics"]["request_count"] , 2)

   #print products[entry]["metrics"]["number_of_first_orders"] ,  total_for_department[products[entry]["department_id"]]
   #print percentage

   # go through all the products and output the metrics   
   print(products[entry]["department_id"], ",",products[entry]["metrics"]["number_of_first_orders"], ",",products[entry]["metrics"]["request_count"], ",", percentage)
```